# laravel _ Method App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Message\categoryController::get_data_delete_message does not exist

Tags: laravel

hi I have this error in my project ,I want to delete a message but I confront with this error ,what should I do?

```
 public function get_data_delete_message(messageCategory $id)
{
    return show_message($this->delete_of_model($id, ['messageCategory']), 'پیام شما با موفقیت حذف گردید');
}
```

my rout is :

```
    Route::get('message/delete/{id}', 'categoryController@get_data_delete_message')->name('Admin.get.page.message.delete');
```

my blade:

```
 <a href="{{route('Admin.get.page.message.delete', $category->id)}}"</a>
```

Comment: maybe check controller name is actualy same? like `CategoryController` not same with `categoryController`

Comment: @ good112233  yes the name is correct

Answer (score 0):

If your controller is under ther path `/Admin/Message`, than you need to provide the same information on the route definition:

```
Route::get('message/delete/{id}', '\Admin\Message\categoryController@get_data_delete_message')->name('Admin.get.page.message.delete');
```

Comment: my routs ->> Route::group(['prefix' => 'message', 'namespace' => 'Message'], function () {
    Route::get('category', 'categoryController@show_page_index')->name('Admin.show.page.message.c
    sage.delete');

Comment: Your group prepends the `Message`, but not the `Admin` part